# finding the average of sums made in a loop in c++

Tags: c++, loops, mean

Hello everyone I'm trying to find the average of a random amount of numbers that are input into a loop.  For sum reason after the loop im able to print the right total, but when i try to find the average i get a weird answer. can anyone help me with this or direct to a thread on here that could help? I wasnt able to find anything on here.

here is my code for the program that isnt working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream inData;
string golferFile;
string golfer;
int matches;
int score;

cout << endl;
cout << "Enter the golfer's filename: ";
cin >> golferFile;
inData.open(golferFile.c_str());
getline(inData, golfer);
inData >> matches;
cout << endl;
cout << "The golfer " << golfer << " has " << matches << " matches with         scores"
          " of" << endl;
cout << endl;
int count;
count = 1;
int matchNumber;
matchNumber = 1;
int sum;
while(count <= matches)
  {
     inData >> score;
     cout << "Match " << matchNumber << ": " << score << endl;
     matchNumber++;
     count++;
     sum = sum + score;
   }
  }
int mean;
mean = sum / matches;
cout << "The mean score is " << mean << endl;
return 0;
}
```

the output i receive is this for the mean

The mean score is 1399255

Comment: would you mind to intialize sum variable.

Comment: Would i have to initialize it to zero before the loop? I have it initialized just in the loop as of right now

Comment: yes do intialize it with zero outside loop.

Comment: You don't initialize it the loop. You use it in the loop. What is `sum + score` if you didn't set an initial value for `sum`?

Comment: wow, i spent like three days trying to figure this out. It was so simple. Thanks guys i appreciate it. it works now

Comment: You should really fix your indentation. It makes the code much easier to read, which in turn makes it easier to catch bugs. The extra brace, for example, would not have happened if you had good indentation.

Comment: A lot of the weird indentation is from when I was adding the spaces to it to post as a code.  I'm only eight weeks into my freshman Computer Science classes so I'm still learning proper forms of coding.  Thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found several error in your code.

- you forget to initialize your `sum` variable.
- in `while` loop an extra brace found.remove it
- you didn't write anything to stop your `loop`.that why your loop run infinite time.so initialize you loop also.